# When is 16.04 going to be officially available on AWS?

Tags: 16.04, cloud, amazon-ec2

It doesn't seem to be avail on http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ nor I can find any when searching on AWS itself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed at Amazons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are kind of released.

If you look at:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/query/xenial/server/released.current.txt you will find the AMI id's.

As of right now though, they are not public, atleast not in eu-west-1. Most likely Amazon is vetting them, because they'll become official images.

Comment: Thanks Rasmus. From your experience when they will be publicly available?

Comment: I don't want to guess... But my advice would be to use the already public beta2 images if you need to test something against 16.04. If you need it for production, then you should probably wait a week anyway, to let things calm down. Sorry... no idea with regards to timing, my guess would be this week.

Comment: Now its July 15th and still no official 16.04 release on AWS.

Comment: Subscribing to this. Still waiting for it to be officially tested.

Comment: So.....on a scale from one to 10, how bad of an idea is it to use one of these images in production?